# How to get ASCII values in SQL Server Compact

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I am using SQL Server Compact Edition and I want to get ASCII value of any character, but I get an error

> The function is not recognized by SQL Server Compact Edition

Query is

```
Select ASCII('a') from table
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is supported starting from SQL Server 2008 and it is not supported for the Compact Edition. Take a look at the documentation.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174077(v=sql.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms177545.aspx